# 20 word recovery phase Metamask

Tags: metamask, binance, trezor

I had a problem with transactions from Binance to Trezor, namely, the amount transferred did not appear in the app. So I am trying to connect my Trezor hardware wallet to a third-party one like MetaMask to manage transactions from Binance. However, when I try to access MetaMask, it just gives me an alternative for 12,18 or 21 recovery phrases and not for 20 words, which I currently own. It seems strange to me that it would not account for different numbers of recovery phrases. Any ideas on the solution and maybe some alternative suggestion on how to manage transactions from Binance

Answer (score 1):

You are not transferring funds to trezor or metamask or anything for that matter. The funds are transferred to ur blockchain address for which you own the private key. Metamask or Trezor are wallets helping you access it. If you sent funds from Binance and it hasnt reached your address, it has nothing to do with Trezor or metamask.

On the question of why you have 21 words in recovery is because when you created a Trezor wallet, you would have created a passphrase. It is one extra word added to the mnemonic seed phrase to create a new wallet for you. The normal browser wallets like metamask or trustwallet generally dont work with it since they cant decode the extra one word/letter like how Trezor would do.

Comment: So what is the issue if my tokens do not appear in the Trezor app nor in MetaMask. I searched for my transaction address in Etherscan and it shows that the transaction only happed through a Binance Smart Chain. This seems like the two are not connected, so how can I access these tokens?

Comment: Is it a token ? Trezor app doesnt show most of the tokens. But if the address has the tokens, means you have them.